# make animation effect wait until the previous effect is done

Tags: jquery

I am making a box move to the right by 200px on each click of a link.

The problem is, if I click the link while the box is moving, it will add the additional 200px. I don't want that to happen before the effect is finished.

So I want to click the link and move the box by 200px, and if I click it again in the meantime (while it's moving) I don't want it to add 200px again.

Can this be done?

My code:

```
#box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

<a href="#" id="link">CLICK</a>
<div id="box"></div>

$('#link').click(function() {
    $('#box').animate({
        'left': '+=100'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before running the animation check to see if it is already animated, using the [animated](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) selector:

```
$('#link').click(function() {
    if(!$("#box").is(":animated")){
       $('#box').animate({
            'left': '+=100'
        });
    }
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8C9Xc/

Answer (score 0):

Just to supplement Kevins answer above. `animate` also has a `complete` function [docs here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

This will allow you to do what the title of your question says (*wait until the previous effect is done*)

e.g.

```
$('#link').click(function() {
    if(!$("#box").is(":animated")){
       $('#box').animate({
            'left': '+=100',
            complete: function() {/*this will run once the animation is complete*/}
        });
    }
});
```